# Trying to reverse a queue in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I'm trying to reverse a queue using recursion. I have already implemented the process using queue and a stack, but I would like to learn the recursive way also.

The following is a code from this [website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reversing-a-queue/)

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class GFG {

// Utility function to print the queue
public static void Print(Queue<Integer> Queue)
{
    while (Queue.size() > 0) {
    System.out.print(Queue.peek() + " ");
    Queue.remove();
    }
}

// Function to reverse the queue
public static void reverseQueue(Queue<Integer> q)
{
    // base case
    if (q.size() == 0)
    return;
    // storing front(first element) of queue
    int fr = q.peek();

    // removing front
    q.remove();

    // asking recursion to reverse the
    // leftover queue
    reverseQueue(q);

    // placing first element
    // at its correct position
    q.add(fr);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Queue<Integer> Queue = new LinkedList<>();

    Queue.add(10);
    Queue.add(20);
    Queue.add(30);
    Queue.add(40);
    Queue.add(50);
    Queue.add(60);
    Queue.add(70);
    Queue.add(80);
    Queue.add(90);
    Queue.add(100);

    reverseQueue(Queue);
    Print(Queue);
}
}
```

Now my doubt exist on the reverseQueue() method, the front value is stored in a variable fr using peek().Now my doubt is that how does this function reverse the queue? The value of fr changes each time. The last value of fr contains lets say 40 from the queue(10,20,30,40). How are the values 30,20 and 10 stored ?

Comment: Do not tag this as `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.  Why didn't you tag the actual language you are using, i.e. `java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How are the values 30,20 and 10 stored ?

This question seems to suggest you think there is only one `fr` variable. This is not true. `fr` is a *local* variable that exists during the execution of `reverseQueue`. And as you have several executions of `reverseQueue`, you have as many `fr` variables, and each has a different value. Once a recursive call finishes and the current execution of `reverseQueue` can continue, it will have access to its own `fr` variable which was not affected by any of the deeper recursive calls.

I hope that clarifies your doubt.

On another subject: your `Print` function removes all elements from the given queue. This is odd: no-one would expect that after printing a queue it ends up empty.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figured out later too. Anyway thanks for the clear explanation. I only encounter hostile people from this forum!

Comment: Hostile? Is that so? I do find many will point out the rules of the site, and what is on topic and what is not, but most do so in good faith, with the intention to help. If you do come across personal attacks, please point me to them, and I'll flag them for moderation.

Comment: You have no idea. I only post here as a last option when I actually need to understand something. I once asked a question, someone said the question was trivial (acceptable), for another question in which I asked about why something was happening related to the question and a guy commented "Why are you asking us, Ask your Computer". Others they just downvote, no answers no comments just downvotes. I usually get answers from people with low reputation ( ~200 )

Comment: Downvotes are just a thing you shouldn't pay attention to that much in my opinion. But yes, "ask your computer" is not a very nice comment, and should be removed. If ever you have a new question, ping me in this thread, and I'll have a look at it.